# Проблема подключения с Windows на Linux

Tags: java, сокет

Есть код на JAVA, не могу подключиться с винды на linux (из 50 попыток одна удалась), хотя в обратную сторону всё корректно работает, в чем может быть дело?

На обеих машинах стоит Java последней версии, исправно работает. Соединение есть, локальная сеть. Повторюсь, использую простейшее подключение через Socket, НИ В КАКОЙ ФОРМЕ не подключается, если сервер Linux. 
Если сервер на первой машине (под управлением ОС Windows), то Linux подключается без проблем, равно как и другие машины с Windows. "Не подключается" в моём случае - сервер не видит клиента, а клиент сервера.

**OC:** ***Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04.***

**Код (сервера)**

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555); 
Socket s = ss.accept();
```

**Код клиента**

```
Socket s = new Socket(..., 5555);
```

Comment: Тут нет телепатов. Может у вас grub полетел, может еще что. Уточните проблему и дайте хотя бы скрины ошибок

Comment: Никаких ошибок, абсолютно, просто ждёт подключения

Comment: А как именно и чем подключаетесь? Вариантов вагон и тележка.

Comment: Это радует, авось какой-нибудь и подойдёт) Подключаюсь проще некуда, через Socket. Если сервер на Linux, то висит бесконечно долго на accept()

Comment: Что-то не видать тележки даже

Comment: Господа, попробуйте осуществить простейшее аналогичное подключение и, в случае успеха, будем знать, что проблема только у меня. Это поможет исключить массу бессмысленных комментариев.

Comment: Код-то какой? Вы из java программы подключаетесь? Если нет, то при чем тут тег java?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос: Какая версия винды, какая линукс, какой код или команды вводите

Comment: @Максим я думал, там ssh/samba/ftp/vnc... а там просто обычный сокет...   В любом случае показывайте полный код

Comment: Разумеется из java, если метка стоит. И через сокет, согласно второй метке. Надеюсь, хотя бы в теме вопроса об этом уточнять не нужно было? Windows 7, Ubuntu 14. Код (сервера) ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555); Socket s = ss.accept(); Код клиента Socket s = new Socket(..., 5555); А есть ли смысл писать версии ОС, в чем разница, какие ошибки свойственны в этих случаях?

Comment: И почему мне минусов наставили, вопрос неактуален? Первый раз тут спрашиваю, и такое фиаско

Comment: Если Вы пишите "не подключается", обычно нужно показать код и описать, как именно не подключается (выводит ошибку, бросает синий экран). Код, который Вы привели, слишком общий. Телепаты тут есть, но они не всегда могут  детально все угадать. Возможные проблемы (навскиду): фаервол, неверный айпи, другой процесс занял порт (или просто другая копия приложения), конфигурация сети (в разных подсетях).

Comment: А  ping от клиента до сервера идет? telnet'ом (или любой альтернативой) запрос на данный id и port отправляли с клиента? Проверяли что порт свободен до запуска и открыт после? Вам нужно в первую очередь понять проблема в java или вообще в вашей сетевой конфигурации.

Comment: на будущее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - как правильно задавать вопросы на SO

Answer (score 0):

Для начала стоит понять, проблема в Java или нет:

1. Попробовать ping от клиента до сервера,
2. Отправить запрос telnet'ом (или любой альтернативой) запрос на данный id и port сервера с клиента,
3. Проверить, то что данный порт не занят до запуска Java приложения и открыт для внешних соединений после,

После этого можно локализовать проблему:

1. Если дело в настройки сети (шанс 90%)- соответственно советоваться со своим сисадмином или уже задавать вопрос в SO в нужный раздел SO,
2. Если дело все-таки в Java можно (маловероятно) - напишите, будем разбираться. Вообще, сокеты в Java хорошо протестированы и часто используются с разными конфигурациями сети, если проблема была именно в любом соединении Linux-Windows, ее заметили и исправили бы давным давно.